# Could someone please explain how this Chrome extension manifest option is put together?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm looking at the http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html documentation and seeing:

```
{
  ...,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'",
  ...
}
```

gets me confused... how is that value put together? What are the relevant pieces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that scripts can be loaded only from the same extension and from https://example.com; media files can only be loaded from the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Taken straight off of the same page:

*For full details regarding CSP's syntax, please take a look at [the Content Security Policy specification](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html#syntax).*